# Creating / populating json w/ array

Tags: python, arrays, json

I can create the following json format:

```
>>> json_response = {}
>>> json_response["data"] = {}
>>> json_response["data"][0] = "bla"
>>> print(json.dumps(json_response))
{"data": {"0": "bla"}}
```

But what I need is this final result:

```
{"data": [{"0": "bla"}]}
```

How do I get there?

Comment: With `json_response = {"data": [{"0": "bla"}]}`. Or just `print('{"data": [{"0": "bla"}]}')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining `json_response["data"] = {}` as a dictionary define it as a list `json_response["data"] = []` and then append your `dict` to it.

```
json_response = {}
json_response["data"] = []
json_response["data"].append({0:"bla"})
print(json.dumps(json_response))
```